# PHP Call to undefined function newuserid()

Tags: php

I tried to put data from a form into a database. But I get a parse error saying that it cant find the function newuserid(). That function is ment to get latest userid in the database and than do +1 for a new user.

Why is this not working? I can't seem to find anything about this on the internet.

Here is a code snippet:

```
/**
        * newuserid - Creates a userid for every user, to link up to other services
        */
       function newuserid() {
           //Get latest userid
           $q = "SELECT userid FROM blog_users ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 1";
           $latest_userid = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);

            $userid = $latest_userid + 1;   
          return $userid;
       }

       /**
        * addNewUser - Inserts the given (username, password, email)
        */
       function addNewUser($userdata){
            //Account
             $username = $userdata['username'];
             $password = $userdata['password'];

            //Personal Information
             $first_name = $userdata['first_name'];
             $last_name = $userdata['last_name'];
             $bdate = $userdata['bdate'];

            //Address  
              $address = $userdata['address'];
              $street_number = $userdata['street_number'];
              $city = $userdata['city'];
              $postal_code = $userdata['postalcode'];

            //Phone & Email
              $email = $userdata['email'];
              $phone = $userdata['phone'];

         $userid = newuserid();

          $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$userid', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$bdate', '$address', '$street_number', '$city', '$postal_code', '$email', '$phone')";
          return mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
       }
```

Does someone know how to fix this, or recode a piece? Sorry, but i don't know alot about PHP, so I might use the wrong therms for some things.

Please help me find the problem.

Comment: Please show use the full and exact error message you get!

Comment: full error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function newuserid() in /var/www/vhosts/ostrealyceum.net/giel-jan.ostrealyceum.net/include/login/database.php on line 143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `$this` in your code i assume that these functions are in a class, so you would have also to use `$this` to call the function like this:

```
$userid = $this->newuserid();
        //^^^^^ If this code is in a class you have to use $this
```